# Proving $\tan^2 20^{\circ} + \frac{3}{16}\csc^2 40^ {\circ}\sec^2 20^{\circ}-\frac{\sqrt3}{4}\tan 20^{\circ} \sec^2 20^{\circ} = 4 \sin^2 20^{\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that
$$\tan^2 20^{\circ} + \frac{3}{16}\csc^2 40^ {\circ}\sec^2 20^{\circ}-\frac{\sqrt3}{4}\tan 20^{\circ} \sec^2 20^{\circ} = 4 \sin^2 20^{\circ}$$

Can I express them in terms of $\tan 20^{\circ}$ and prove it?

Comment: prove the identity, that means prove that left hand side equals right hand side

Comment: Are these all degrees or radian?

Comment: all degrees, I am sure

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: What have you tried. I find it easiest to put this in terms for sins and cosines.  A lot should simplify. the only tricky part I see is $ \csc^2 40 = \frac 1{\sin (20 + 20)}$ which should be straight forward.

Comment: Yes I see it too. But what's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=20^\circ$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\tan^2 20^{\circ} + \frac{3}{16}\csc^2 40^ {\circ}\sec^2 20^{\circ}-\frac{\sqrt3}{4}\tan 20^{\circ} \sec^2 20^{\circ}-4\sin^2 20^\circ\\
&=&\frac{1}{\cos^2 x\sin^2(2x)}\bigg[\frac{3}{16}-\sqrt3\cos x\sin^3x+4\cos^2x\sin^4x-\sin^4(2x)\bigg].\\
\end{eqnarray}
Noting
$$ \sin 60^\circ=\sin(3x)=-4\sin^3x+3\sin x=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}, \cos 60^\circ=\cos(3x)=4\cos^3x-3\cos x=\frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$ \sin 120^\circ=\sin(6x)=-4\sin^3(2x)+3\sin(2x)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$
one has
$$ 4\sin^3x=-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+3\sin x,4\cos^3x=\frac12+3\cos x, 4\sin^3(2x)=-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+3\sin(2x) $$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{3}{16}-\sqrt3\cos x\sin^3x+4\cos^2x\sin^4x-\sin^4(2x)\\
&=&\frac{3}{16}-\frac{\sqrt3}{4}\cos x\bigg(-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+3\sin x\bigg)+\cos^2 x\sin x\bigg(-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+3\sin x\bigg)\\
&&-\frac14\sin(2x)\bigg(-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+3\sin(2x)\bigg)\\
&=&\frac{3}{16}+\frac{3}{8}\cos x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\sin (2x)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\cos x \sin(2x)\\
&=&\frac{3}{16}+\frac{3}{8}\cos x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\sin (2x)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}(\sin 60°+\sin x)\\
&=&\frac18 \bigg(3\cos x-\sqrt3 \bigg(\sin x+2\sin(2x)\bigg)\bigg).
\end{eqnarray}
Noting
$$ \sin x+2\sin(2x)=\sin x+2\sin(60^\circ-x)=\sqrt3\cos x$$
it is easy to check that
$$ 3\cos x-\sqrt3(\sin x+2\sin(2x))=0 $$
and hence
$$ \frac{3}{16}-\sqrt3\cos x\sin^3x+4\cos^2x\sin^4x-\sin^4(2x)=0.$$

Comment: Could you show some steps after changing the trigonmetric function into imaginary number form?

Comment: @RayCheng, check the update of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-prove-that-sin-20%C2%B0-+-2-sin-40%C2%B0-sqrt-3-cos-20%C2%B0/answer/Peter-Tran-93?**filter**=all&**nsrc**=1&**snid3**=1261438578](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-prove-that-sin-20%C2%B0-+-2-sin-40%C2%B0-sqrt-3-cos-20%C2%B0/answer/Peter-Tran-93?__filter__=all&__nsrc__=1&__snid3__=1261438578)

After I asked a question at Quora, I am sure that in order to show that $3\cos x-\sqrt3(\sin x+2\sin(2x))=0$, where $x=20°$, this is actually equivalent to show that  $\tan 60°\cos20°-\sin20°=2\sin 40°$. Using this approach, we don't need to use imaginary numbers (Euler's formula).

$\tan 60°\cos20°-\sin20°=\frac{1}{\cos 60°}(\sin 60° \cos 20°-\cos 60° \sin 20°)=2 \sin(60°-20°)=2 \sin 40°.$